# CSS multi level drop down menu position next level

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how a css drop down can be positioned (x axis). At the moment it looks like this:

Top Level (you hover and this appears)

- Second level
- Second Level (hover)
- Second Level

When you hover over the second level the third level appears underneath it, how do i position it so every time its at the side? Thanks :)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YgYtL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the jsFiddle with this code in the css

```
#navMenu ul li ul li:hover ul{
    top : 0;
    left : 100%;
}
```

here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/YgYtL/16/

Comment: you don't really want to position an element on hover, that should be left on the main element declaration.

Comment: If he has multiple third level items, he should also change the #navMenu ul ul ul li, remove the position, display and float. At the moment they stick together because of the absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

Target your third level dropdown and position it exactly 100% from the left of your second level element, which should be the whole width of your second level dropdown, like so:

```
#navMenu ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YgYtL/24/